# extern on function prototypes?

Tags: c, extern, function-prototypes

#### my_math.h

```
// case 1 
unsigned int add_two_numbers(unsigned char a, unsigned char b);

//case 2 
extern unsigned int add_two_numbers(unsigned char a, unsigned char b);
```

What is the difference between case 1 and case 2? I never used *extern* for function prototypes but looking at someone's code (who is way more experienced than I am) I see *extern* always used when declaring the function prototype. Can anyone point please point the difference? (or point me to a link where I can find specific information). Google says that is something related to the external linkage. Can anyone point me to an example where one would work and the other wouldn't?

I am using embedded C (KEIL), if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 17):

`extern` is a linkage specifier for global linkage. Its counterpart is `static`, which specifies file-local linkage. Since global linkage is the default in C, **adding `extern` to the declaration makes no difference for the declaration of a function**. For a variable it prevents automatic memory allocation and using it is the only way to *just* declare a variable at global scope.

If you just google the keyword, you will find many articles e.g. this one:
[geeks for geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/)

Answer (score 2):

I learned the following for variables years ago from an experienced programmer:

```
glo.h:
#ifndef EXTERN
#define EXTERN extern
#endif
...
EXTERN int gMyVar;
...

main.c:
#define EXTERN
#include "glo.h"
```

"glo.h" anywhere inlcuded will just declare all global variables. "glo.h" included in main.c will allocate the storage for the variables. I believe this method was common practice.

Comment: Interesting approach, but to me it just seems more straightforward to just have a glo.c file with the variable declarations.  No need for preprocessor directives.

Comment: @jgoeders, the approach requires the symbols to be declared only once. Yours requires them to be declared at least twice, which is error prone when renaming/adding/deleting symbols. Note that only in `main` is a `#define` required; all other files only need a `#include "glo.h"`.

Comment: I agree, your posted method does eliminate some duplication, although the .c/.h definition/declaration approach only has a single definition and single declaration, not more, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting by "at least twice". There is lots of discussion of both methods (and others) here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files

Comment: "At least twice" means there is at least one time an `extern int myvar;` declaration and exactly one `int myvar;` definition. My schme is described verbatim in your linked question under the header "Avoiding Code Duplication" (which is exactly my point).

Answer (score 1):

For a (non-`inline`) function, it doesn't make any difference, `extern` is implicit if no storage-class specifier is given (note, that this applies only to functions, objects are different), so it's only a matter of style what you use.

I've seen both (never use `extern` for functions/only use it for the declarations in the header), maybe some use `extern` for symmetry with object identifiers, or to make it easier to grep for external symbols.

Choose whatever you prefer and stay consistent, it doesn't make a difference.